# How to use Jooq mapper in 3.9.2

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I would like to use the system to provide the mapper, how to use? Or how do you implement one?

eg:

```
public List<com.chunfytseng.microedu.jooq.tables.pojos.SysResources> findResourceByUserId(Long value) {
        using(configuration()).
           select(SysRoleResources.SYS_ROLE_RESOURCES.ROLE_ID, 
                   SysRoleResources.SYS_ROLE_RESOURCES.RESOURCES_ID,
                   SysRoleResources.SYS_ROLE_RESOURCES.PERMS)
          .from(SysRoleResources.SYS_ROLE_RESOURCES)
          .leftSemiJoin(SysUserRole.SYS_USER_ROLE)
          .on(SysRoleResources.SYS_ROLE_RESOURCES.ROLE_ID.eq(SysUserRole.SYS_USER_ROLE.ROLE_ID).
                  and(SysUserRole.SYS_USER_ROLE.USER_ID.equal(value)))
          .fetch().map(mapper());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`RecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/RecordMapper.html) can be implemented very easily as follows:

#### Java 8 style

```
fetch().map(record -> {
    SysResources result = new SysResources();
    result.setRoleId(record.get(SYS_ROLE_RESOURCS.ROLE_ID));
    result.setResourcesId(record.get(SYS_ROLE_RESOURCS.RESOURCES_ID));
    result.setPerms(record.get(SYS_ROLE_RESOURCS.PERMS));
    return result;
});
```

#### Java 7 and older style:

```
fetch().map(new RecordMapper<Record, SysResources>() {
    @Override
    public SysResources map(Record record) {
        SysResources result = new SysResources();
        result.setRoleId(record.get(SYS_ROLE_RESOURCS.ROLE_ID));
        result.setResourcesId(record.get(SYS_ROLE_RESOURCS.RESOURCES_ID));
        result.setPerms(record.get(SYS_ROLE_RESOURCS.PERMS));
        return result;
    }
});
```